# ¿como pasar los datos obtenidos desde useFetch a un componente en nuxt 3?

Tags: vue.js, vue3, nuxt, composition-api

tengo un componente llamado mapa ese componente usa un composable function donde traigo desde una api datos que necesito cargar para utilizar mapbox.
Este es mi composable

```
const getMunicipios = async (uuid: string | null = null) => {
  const config = useRuntimeConfig()
  if(uuid){
    const { data } = await useFetch(`${config.baseURL}/municipios/${uuid}`);
    
    return {
      data
    }
  }else { 
    const { data } = await useFetch(`${config.baseURL}/municipios`);
    
    return {
      data
    }
  }
}

export default getMunicipios;
```

quiero pasar esta data a un componente de la siguiente manera

```
<script lang="ts" setup>
   const { data } = await getMunicipios('f0eaa355-732f-41e3-bd3d-92eff4e29479');
</script>
<tempate>


<MapboxMap
    map-id="map"
    class="relative top-0 bottom-0 left-0 w-full h-full"
    :options="{
      style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v12', // style URL
      center: [data.value.longitude, data.value.latitude], // no encuentra ni logitude ni latitude
      zoom: 2, // starting zoom
    }"
 ></MapboxMap>

</template>
```

Aparece este error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

lo logico es pensar que seguramente mi data no tiene absolutamente nada pero cuando le hago console.log() si hay datos, mi composable si realiza mi petición

```
Object { __v_isShallow: false, dep: undefined, __v_isRef: true, _rawValue: {…}, _value: Proxy }
​
__v_isRef: true
​
__v_isShallow: false
​
_rawValue: Object { id: "f0eaa355-732f-41e3-bd3d-92eff4e29479", latitude: "5.06906", … }
​
_value: Proxy { <target>: {…}, <handler>: {…} }
```

(lo anterior es parte de la salida de mi console.log)

Comment: Al pasarlo al componente debe envolverlo en una función asíncrona para poder usar await y extraer el dato al componente. Cual es el error?